# How to make the game object unthorough able?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, triggers, collider

I was looking for most of the threads that have the similar question as mine, but still cant seem to solve my issue.
I'm working on a game, that in the ends when u finish the tasks, a gate should open up and after u walk thought it you're up to the next level. - got the gate, got the animation working when the goal is complete. but for some reason my player can go through the gate even though both player and gate have Box collider + Rigid Body. (I'll put here the pic)
I think I know is because the player is trigger so that what makes the player go through. but is there a code? or another way to make that gate solid? as long until it opens and then the player can go through.(I know that what makes it happened is because the player isTrigger, I need it to be trigger so other function will work as they should be, but still there is other ways to make it work?)

[image: Gate Inspector(Left Door for now)]

[image: Player Inspector]

Thank you soo much for the help

Comment: enable the box collider on the leftgate and disable the istrigger checkbox on both

Comment: yeah this is it. i cant disable is trigger on player coz he does some mechanic allready with it. i need it to stay Is trigger/

Comment: then it will behave as a trigger, not as a collider

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have more than one collider added if you want that. isTrigger will always allow things to pass through, it's a trigger zone when you enable that boolean, that means it doesn't block objects by colliding with them.

So if you want both an "isTrigger" and a normal collider you would need to use 2 colliders on the object in question. Or on both if you want it on both.